# How to send a message to a client using WampSharp?

Tags: wampsharp

Is it possible to do this way:
WampSharp client app connects to a WampSharp Server, then this server sends message/call client's function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client can subscribe to a topic and then you can publish to this topic, specifying in the publish options' eligible property the session id of the client.

For functions this is more tricky - you would need to register the procedure with a unique name which depends on the client's session id and then call it from the server side.

Comment: Thank you. How do you think: what is the better way to implement such schema: Client connects to Server, then Server sends messages via this channel to the Client. I'd like to build smth like reversing tunnel  to the Cloud.

Comment: Perhaps the client should call a procedure that creates a ephemeral topic (which is its return value) to which the client will subscribe. The server could send relevant messages to this channel.

Comment: Ok, thnx, will try it. Here: client calls remote proc(server-side) to create a topic? If I understand correctly: Client calls server-proc, it creates topic and returns value to caller, client subscribes to it, then server can send messages to this channel.

Comment: What is better client/server samples pair to use for this kind of scenarios?

Comment: You got it right. Declare a class with a WampProcedure (see reflection-based callee samples) and register it to the realm services. In that procedure, create a topic using the IWampTopicContainer api (undocumented) and start publishing to it using the realm services api (or perhaps using the IWampTopicContainer api). See also publisher api documentation.